# Node.js npm install ETIMEDOUT

Tags: node.js, npm

I am trying to run a demo program.

As per the instruction I have to run the command `npm install`, which install all the dependencies but facing the problem as below

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try the following command, it changes the registry's protocol from https to http.

```
npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try

```
npm config set proxy null
```

It worked for me on date I posted this.