# Electron install npm: ETIMEDOUT error; IP not accesible

Tags: node.js, npm, electron

I am new to npm and immediately lost. I'm trying to install electron as per the docs: https://www.electronjs.org/docs/v14-x-y/tutorial/quick-start

I installed node using nvm and my node version is 17.3. and npm 8.3.

when running `npm install --save-dev --verbose electron` I get the following error at the end of the install process when postinstall is being run:

```
npm ERR! path /home/mackesmilian/dev/fun/lorikeet/node_modules/electron
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c node install.js
npm ERR! RequestError: connect ETIMEDOUT 64:ff9b::8c52:7904:443
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/home/mackesmilian/dev/fun/lorikeet/node_modules/got/source/request-as-event-emitter.js:178:14)
npm ERR!     at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:510:26)
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:402:35)
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.origin.emit (/home/mackesmilian/dev/fun/lorikeet/node_modules/@szmarczak/http-timer/source/index.js:37:11)
npm ERR!     at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:442:9)
npm ERR!     at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:390:28)
npm ERR!     at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:164:8)
npm ERR!     at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:129:3)
npm ERR!     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)
```

According to the electron [docs](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/v14-x-y/tutorial/installation#troubleshooting):

> Errors like ELIFECYCLE, EAI_AGAIN, ECONNRESET, and ETIMEDOUT are all indications of such network problems. The best resolution is to try switching networks, or wait a bit and try installing again.

Well I've been trying this for 3 hours now with no change. Things I tried:

- reinstall node
- [set the registry](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34932409/10347787)
- [set proxy to null](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45094563/10347787)

Then I tried to ping `64:ff9b::8c52:7904:443` which did not work. What do I do now? I really am super confused.

Comment: Did your machine has a valid IPv6 configuration? (BTW: you dont ping the port, only the IP)

Comment: @Marc I tried pinging both (with and wo/ port because I was desperate) because neither worked. Changing networks to my phone worked and today it suddenly worked on my original network. Why it didn’t work in the first place is kind of a mistery to me.